# SQLite how to select row based on a column max

Tags: sqlite

I have the following table

```
UserID, Cost, date 
1.       23.   2015-04-02
2.       17.   2015-03-14
1.       63.   2015-09-23
2.       49.   2013-03-17
2.       12.   2013-04-23
1.       96.   2016-01-01
```

What I want is a list of USERID & date with the largest cost

So

```
Userid 1 cost 96 date 2016-01-01
Userid 2 cost 49 date 2013-03-17
```

I have tried

select date, userid, max(cost) from table group by userid

But I'm confused with will the date always be from the correct row

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, values from other columns are guaranteed to come from a row that matches the max().

Answer (score 0):

Consider a generalized approach for most RDMS versions. Below uses a derived table subquery:

```
SELECT t2.UserID, t2.MaxOfCost, t1.Date
FROM Table t1
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT UserID, Max(Cost) As MaxOfCost,      
      FROM Table) t2
ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID 
AND t1.Cost = t2.MaxOfCost
```